# req.setEndpoint not working when a string with resource name is add

Tags: callout, httprequest

I have a http request like this:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:RSM'+method);
```

where method is a string with a resource name that depending on certain conditions changes the value

the problem is just `req.setEndpoint('callout:RSM');` works although I get an error which is expected. This works too `req.setEndpoint('the/actual/endPoint'+method);`

I don't want to create a custom label or metadata or setting. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the named credentials of RSM there was `'/'` at the end. Removing it and adding it to the beginning of the `method` variable string did the trick for me.